# Round Robin Tournament with no games back to back and games against similar rated opponents at the end

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So lets say we have 8 teams a-h. They are listed by league-ranking, a being the best team, h being the worst. I wonder if theres a way to create a round robin tournament with 28 games where the similar ranked teams play against each other last (a-b; c-d; e-f; g-h;) while still having no games back to back. I've tried to shuffle things around manually but couldnt get it to work so far to ensure that theres no game back to back.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Look into "*Swiss*" tournaments.  This is implemented by a number of systems online such as melee.gg or eventlink and others used by major games.

Comment: What is back to back game?